# JTable for rendering an unknown number of rows

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, rendering

I have a database query returning a large number of rows. `JDBC` doesn't tell you how many rows come back and there are too many rows to count them before I display it in a `JTable`.

So the model I'm working with is an `Iterable<R>`, but unfortunately, `TableRowModel` has to know the row count up-front.

I can imagine a few strategies which might work:

- Load all rows, but do it in the background and add them to the model in batches.
- Somehow detect requests to render the lower rows (via the model I guess) and dynamically load more rows if this happens.
- Have a button on the screen to explicitly load more rows.
- Some kind of `non-JTable` component which supports rendering rows without knowing the row count in advance (ideal, but I can't find one.)

I am wondering if there is a "normal" way to do this, because it isn't often that I see this sort of thing in a UI. The few `JDBC` tools I have checked out (I figured these would be the best bet) seem to either eagerly load the results or page them (as a user, I really dislike paging in GUI apps, so I would like to avoid that.)

Operations like "Find" over the table should ideally work in an "understandable" way though... so it seems like this is not going to be too easy.

Comment: I have been using select count(column) ... to get an approximate number of rows, if you want to load all the data in one go. By the way, if you use DefaultTableModel, you should be able to able to add data in it using its addRow method.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) in your implementation of [`AbstractTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). Let the worker partition the query so that a reasonable number of records are available promptly, while the rest are read in the background. Use a `PropertyChangeListener` to show progress and implement a cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities:

1. Write query, which returns the number of rows, and then implement
   table model, which tries to load rows from the database, if table
   want to show the rows which are not in the model. In this case you need the third query,
   which can index based load the rows (these queries are possible in
   MS-SQL and Oracle). For example: you loads the first 100 rows, and
   the number of results. If table model is asked for rows from
   position 100 to 199 you makes new query, which loads these rows
   interval (if it's possible for your database) or you tries to
   iterate over your result set, and load the next data batch. But if
   user presses the "End" key you definitly needs the index based
   loading (or you need to iterate over the complete result set).
2. You write model, which shows, the first batch (for example 100
       rows). If user, scrolls to view the last row (model.getValueAt(row,
       col) -> col == 99) you simply asks the result set for next batch and
       add the new rows to the model.

First variant is better for the user (because the user can see how large is the table and can directly scroll to last row), but the second is easier to implement because it does not need index based loading of rows.

Comment: This is using Derby, so actually, doing a COUNT(*) involves iterating the rows, and is slow. :(

Comment: OK, but you can implement the second way. First way can be implemented only over SQL and JDBS.

Comment: Yeah, your method 2 corresponds to the 2nd method I listed in the question. :)   I'm not really interested in "ways I can do it", I listed four ways to do it already. I was just searching out for the "common"/"right" way to do it.